# I have 3 columns [A, B, C] in my SQL table. I want to find table entries, where values in A is same, in B is same, but C is different

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns [A, B, C] in my SQL table. I want to find table entries, where values in A is same, in B is same, but C is different.

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
4  5  6
*3  4  5*
*3  4  6*
*7  8  9*
6  1  2
*7  8  3*
```

I want to preferably get something like:

```
A  B  C
3  4  5
3  4  6
7  8  9
7  8  3
```

as my result.
Thanks :)

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  SQL is just a language and doesn't tell us which product you are actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of the solution below is to aggregate over your table on both columns `A` and `B`, and then retain those groups having more than one `C` value.  Then join your full table to this aggregation query to retain only the records you want.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A, B
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY A, B
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
ORDER BY
    t1.A, t1.B;
```

[image]

Here is a demo in MySQL, though the above query should run on pretty much any other database with little modification.

### Demo

Comment: Couldn't it be done using distinct self-join on, e.g. `t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c <> t2.c`?

Comment: @StanMcGeek Yes, that looks like a viable alternative.  You may post that as an answer if you wish.  The only drawback is that for A,B pairs having more than 2 different C values, you get back lots of duplicate records.  The distinct operation basically does an aggregation, the same as my query.

Comment: @Rex Which database are you using?  There are many ways to do this, but some depend on the database type.

Comment: Guess grouping and joining is little bit much work for such basic operation :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select A,B,C from (
    select A,B,C, avg(C * 1.0) over (partition by A,B) [avg] from MY_TABLE
) a where [avg] <> C
```

The idea behind is simple, if all numbers within a set are equal, they also are equal to the average of the set.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t1.* 
FROM 
  test t1 
INNER JOIN 
  test t2 ON t2.a = t1.a 
  AND t2.b = t1.b 
  AND t2.c <> t1.c;
```

Here's a demo: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20cbc/2)

I'm not sure about performance due to lots of duplicates being generated/truncated compared to other solutions, though.

Answer (score 0):

No need to count or rank; you only want to check if *at least one* qualifying row `EXISTS`

---

```
select *
from thetable tt
where exists(
        select * from thetable x
        where x.a = tt.a and x.b = tt.b
        and x.c <> tt.c
        );
```